# Schema of nuget packages.lock.json file generated by locking dependencies during restore

Tags: package, nuget, locking, restore

I can enable the `packages.lock.json` files to be generated as described in this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#locking-dependencies

An example `packages.lock.json` file may look like this:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1": {
      "Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[1.0.0, )",
        "resolved": "1.0.0",
        "contentHash": "7D2TMufjGiowmt0E941kVoTIS+GTNzaPopuzM1/1LSaJAdJdBrVP0SkZW7AgDd0a2U1DjsIeaKG1wxGVBNLDMw=="
      },
      "Newtonsoft.Json": {
        "type": "Direct",
        "requested": "[12.0.3, )",
        "resolved": "12.0.3",
        "contentHash": "6mgjfnRB4jKMlzHSl+VD+oUc1IebOZabkbyWj2RiTgWwYPPuaK1H97G1sHqGwPlS5npiF5Q0OrxN1wni2n5QWg=="
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there documentation around the schema of this file and what it means? I notice fields like `type`, `resolved`, `contentHash`, etc. under the `dependencies` node.

Sometimes the nodes might follow these patterns:

```
"Microsoft.Win32.Primitives": {
        "type": "Transitive",
        "resolved": "4.3.0",
        "contentHash": "9ZQKCWxH7Ijp9BfahvL2Zyf1cJIk8XYLF6Yjzr2yi0b2cOut/HQ31qf1ThHAgCc3WiZMdnWcfJCgN82/0UunxA==",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.1.0",
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Targets": "1.1.0",
          "System.Runtime": "4.3.0"
        }
      }
```

or

```
"somenameclient": {
        "type": "Project",
        "dependencies": {
          "SomeNameClientLib": "1.0.0",
          "RRRBase": "1.0.0"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, they have not created or posted a .json schema file for the format of the NuGet packages.lock.json file. The official documentation [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Repeatable-build-using-lock-file-implementation) makes no mention of it.

The closest thing you will get are:

- [Description of a lock file](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Repeatable-build-using-lock-file-implementation#description-of-a-lock-file)
- [Lock File Format](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Repeatable-build-using-lock-file-implementation#lock-file-format)

...from the above link.